# First element of NodeList in document.body.childNodes

Tags: javascript, dom

There is  HTML page with contents like this.

[image]

Documentation at MDN says that `childNodes returns a collection of child nodes of the given element` which is a NodeList.

So, according to the doc, the first child for the NodeList should be `<h1>PyCon Video Archive</h1>`.

But, in Developer Tools (Chromium), it says the other way.

![enter image description here][2]

> So, why exactly the first node is not `<h1>PyCon Video Archive</h1>`?
>   Why a text object as first element?

I would appreciate some help here.

> EDIT

So, I just figured out that in Firebug (FF), the same function behaves differently.

[image]

***My new question:***  Is using .childNodes() an unreliable way of accessing DOM elements?

Comment: Please don't change the question after you've got answers. By all means edit the question to reflect new information, but *changing* the question strikes me, while I'm obviously biased, as being disrespectful of posted answers. If you have a *new* question, *ask a new question.*

Comment: @DavidThomas It's the same question, just a new development. FF behaves as expected but not Chrome. What's your say on this?

Comment: Your questions are different. "So, why exactly the first node is not `<h1>PyCon Video Archive</h1>`? Why a text object as first element?" is not the same as "Is using `.childNodes()` an unreliable way of accessing DOM elements?"

Comment: @shadyabhi: There *is no expectation* for consoles. They behave however they want, because they're not part of the language. Both browsers are giving you a text node. But they're just showing a different representation of it in their console. The real incompatibility is between older versions of IE, and other browsers. IE will give you the `<h1>`, while correct browsers will give you the text node.

Comment: @amnotiam Thanks. I will write greasemonkey scripts and look more into this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first element child, you can use...

```
document.body.firstElementChild;
```

...but older brwosers don't support it.

---

A method that has greater support is the `children` collection...

```
document.body.children[0];
```

...which has pretty good support but still has some holes in terms of older browsers.

*(Just double checked, and as long as you don't support Firefox 3, and as long as you don't include HTML code comments in the markup, using `.children` will be safe.)*

---

To ensure that you have the widest browser support, create a function...

```
function firstElementChild( parent ) {

    var el = parent.firstChild;
    while( el && el.nodeType !== 1 )
        el = el.nextSibling;

    return el;
}
```

and use it like this...

```
var h1 = firstElementChild( document.body );
```

Comment: To ensure that you have the widest browser support, use the [DOM-shim](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim). Specifically [getFirstElementChild](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim/blob/master/src/ie8/interfaces/Element.js#L30)

Answer (score 1):

Because there's a white-space text-node before the `h1` element. Presumably, in the source (if you view source), the `h1` opening tag's been either indented, or moved to a new line within the body (or both) in order for readability. At a guess, I'd imagine that it's something like the following:

```
<body>
    <h1>PyCon Video Archive</h1>
    <!-- ...other html... -->
```

If you revise that to:

```
<body><h1>PyCon Video Archive</h1><!-- ...other html... -->
```

Then the first childNode will, indeed, be the `h1` element.

It's worth noting that text, even outside of an element tag, is still a child-node of the parent element. Albeit one that can't be easily targeted with a selector.

Comment: But, first node is not a `whitespace`.

Comment: If you look at the nodeValue in the image you posted it *looks* like it contains a newline followed by whitespace? Looking at the `length`, I think it's a newline followed by four spaces.

Comment: Also worth noting that IE < 9 ignores these white space nodes, so using `document.body.childNodes[1]` would not be reliable either.

Comment: Yup. I have this feeling that iteration and assessment of the nodeType (or nodeName) and nodeValue is going to be the way to detect and deal with white-space for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @DavidThomas: `children` returns just element children is almost usable on the general web now.

Comment: Absolutely, but for those occasions where you *want* to deal with, and target, the text-nodes (it's rare enough, certainly, but does come up occasionally) still, so far as I can tell, need to iterate and assess.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Yes, 100% agreed.

Comment: @DavidThomas I understand about whitespaces but why a wall of text? Why not just a `whitespace` when I type document.body.childNodes[0]? And, if using childNodes is not a reliable way, what is a reliable way?

Comment: @DavidThomas I appreciate your reply. I wanted a reliable way of getting `<h1>PyCon Video Archive</h1>`. But, please tell my original question.  why a wall of text? Why not just a whitespace when I type document.body.childNodes[0]? The URL I am working on is http://rbw.goe.net/pycon/ .

Comment: I honestly don't know, I'm afraid. I'd hazard a guess that it's because while it is white-space, it's *also*, and more importantly, *text*. But that's an intuitive answer, and backed up by absolutely nothing other than my own thoughts.

Comment: `el.children` is recommended because it's DOM4 and works in oldIE. Use a DOM-shim if you want other legacy browser compliance.

Comment: @shadyabhi: You need to remember that in JavaScript, you don't deal with HTML markup. You deal with DOM nodes, which are the objects that are rendered after the HTML markup has been parsed. These objects have properties just like any other objects.

Comment: @amnotiam Pls see the edited question. I observed that in FF, everything is working as expected. First childNode has whitespace characters in FF. So, should I never use childNodes?

Comment: @shadyabhi: You need to realize that you're looking at whatever the console decided to display for the node. Firefox may decide to display it as HTML, and Chrome may decide to display it as the DOM node properties. Doesn't matter. They're the same thing. If you want the text *content*, you'd use the `.data` or `.nodeValue` property of the node. `document.body.childNodes[0].data`